# sending a soap request from python

Tags: python, soap, suds

I'm trying to send a soap request using the suds python package as below:

```
from suds.client import Client
WSDL_URL = 'file:/home/Documents/soap/getttt.wsdl'
client = Client(WSDL_URL, cache=None)
result = client.service.GET_TTT(H_ID="01",
                                TTT_ID="44825955",
                                VERSION_DATE="2010-12-01",
                                ACC="B9800B4930543BC4FB305124EDFF7846")
print result
```

It works fine with a simple wsdl with http uri, but I need to load this wsdl using the file protocol and this wsdl is much more complicated. It imports xsd files like so:

```
   <types>
      <xsd:schema>
         <xsd:import schemaLocation="GET_TTT.xsd" namespace="http://example.com"/>
         <xsd:import schemaLocation="TTT_TABLES.xsd" namespace="http://example.com"/>
      </xsd:schema>
   </types>
```

It is failing with this error message:

```
  File "suds_client.py", line 17, in <module>
    ACC="B9800B4930543BC4FB305124EDFF7846")
  File "python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 542, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 602, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
  File "python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 637, in send
    reply = transport.send(request)
  File "python2.7/site-packages/suds/transport/https.py", line 64, in send
    return  HttpTransport.send(self, request)
  File "python2.7/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 77, in send
    fp = self.u2open(u2request)
  File "python2.7/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 118, in u2open
    return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

Any ideas how to debug this? Do I need to use ImportDoctor to load xsd files or does it load them automatically? If I do, then how to load all xsd files?
I am able to send the request from that wsdl using a software called soapUI.
Thanks

Comment: Instead of loading the WSDL using the file protocol, have you tried serving it through localhost, e.g. using SimpleHTTPServer?

Comment: thank you, I did not know about that. I tried it, but I ran into the same problem. Also, note that it is mentioning my ACC parameter only in the error message. Any other adeas?

Comment: I tried using another python package called pysimplesoap. I get a pretty similar error message with an additional info: urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 501: Unsupported method ('POST')

Comment: I discovered that I should use the factory method to create objects and pass objects as parameters. That's why it is complaining about the type of the ACC parameter. For the ACC parameter, the type is define as: <xs:attribute name="ACC" type="xs:hexBinary" use="required"/>

Comment: but I cannot find the definition of hexBinary: client.factory.create('hexBinary') gives me an error: suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: 'hexBinary'. Is there a way to retrieve the parameter types of a soap service for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If I just use strings as parameters, it complains about the parameter and says

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

Looking at:

```
<xs:complexType name="T_GET_TTT">
                <xs:attribute name="HES_ID" type="com:hesHesID" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="TTT_ID" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="VERSION_DATE" type="xs:date" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="ACC" type="xs:hexBinary" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

then I decided to use the proper type imported form the xml schema using the doctor:

```
imp = Import('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema')
d = ImportDoctor(imp)
imp.filter.add('http://aa')
client = Client(WSDL_URL, cache=None, doctor=d)
print client
client.factory.create('xs:string')
```

my print command shows that I have the xs:string type:
but I get this error:

Exception: prefix (xs) not resolved

Any ideas why it thinks that xs is not a prefix but rather part of the type name?