# Connect to Amadeus (http://webservices.amadeus.com/) soap api connection using python

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, suds, amadeus

I am very new in Python as well as I am not used Amadeus API before,
I trying to make connection from Amadeus(http://webservices.amadeus.com/) soap API, I have .wsdl file and i want to send request and get response using python.
I have looked SOAPpy, suds,and try to use as well, like this example:

[sending a soap request from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902517/sending-a-soap-request-from-python)

But I am not able to determine request is going up to server or not, if request is going how to get response data.

Please help me Thanks in advance.

Comment: i just started working with Amadeus. How has your experience been so far? Im using PHP, but have not been able to get the WSDL file yet, what URL do you use to connect?

Answer (score 0):

If you enable debug logging for the transport library.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.transport.http').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

You will be able to see something like this in the log output:

```
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:sending:
URL: http://someurl
HEADERS: {'SOAPAction': '"http://blablabla/identityCheck"', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Soapaction': '"http://blablabla/blablabla"'}
MESSAGE: <xml......>
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:received:
CODE: 200
HEADERS: {'header1': 'blablabla'}
MESSAGE: <xml......>
```

Additionally you can also print out the service result object. This assumes I have a method called identityCheck in the endpoint and it customer as input.

```
client = Client(wsdl_url, location=endpoint_url)
customer = client.factory.create('customer')
customer.userId = 'A'
customer.password = 'B'

result = client.service.identityCheck(customer)
print result
```